# sub popen multiple files

Tags: python, matplotlib, subprocess

Is it possible to use sub popen to open multiple files?

The code I am using is for a GUI and upon selecting a button, it should open the png file but I need the button to open more than one png file. 
my code:

```
def look2():
            sub.Popen('open myplot1.png', stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Comment: yeah, did you try that? it should work. but don't redirect both streams to PIPE as it can deadlock. Don't redirect or redirect to os.devnul

Comment: Aah i fixed it while i was waiting for someone to reply. I just had to put x amount of sub.Popen commands with the files i wanted to open! haha thanks!

Comment: @skcoder If you figured it out can you post the solution as an answer and accept it? This will mark the question as resolved and help anyone else in the future who had the same problem.